# Unable to mount BTRFS partition on RAID 5

Tags: linux, raid, btrfs

I recently had a power outage, upon rebooting I was unable to mount my btrfs partition which is set up as raid 5.

```
root@ubuntu:~# mdadm -D /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Jun  6 20:37:19 2019
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 8776333632 (8369.76 GiB 8986.97 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2925444544 (2789.92 GiB 2995.66 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri Sep  6 11:48:27 2019
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : design:2
              UUID : 6bdfacf4:608de1bd:c9e76f1f:b66e55f7
            Events : 1179

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       4       8       83        0      active sync   /dev/sdf3
       5       8       35        1      active sync   /dev/sdc3
       2       8       19        2      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       3       8        3        3      active sync   /dev/sda3
```

below is the current btrfs filesystem

```
root@ubuntu:~# btrfs filesystem show

Label: '2019.06.08-23:28:42 v24922'  uuid: e3675fea-e2bb-4261-b53e-4833844e9527
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 7.41TiB
    devid    1 size 8.17TiB used 7.65TiB path /dev/md2
```

When I try to mount it, I get the following error.

```
root@ubuntu:~# mount -vs -t btrfs -o ro,recovery,errors=continue /dev/md2 /mnt


mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I had seen an answer on the question below about repairing by tree root, I followed the commands, but am now stuck about which block to pick for tree root

[BTRFS: is it possible to switch to another tree root?](https://superuser.com/questions/1131909/btrfs-is-it-possible-to-switch-to-another-tree-root)

So, I ran the first command to list the superblocks, they look ok I assume.

```
root@ubuntu:~# btrfs rescue super-recover -v /dev/md2

All Devices:
    Device: id = 1, name = /dev/md2

Before Recovering:
    [All good supers]:
        device name = /dev/md2
        superblock bytenr = 65536

        device name = /dev/md2
        superblock bytenr = 67108864

        device name = /dev/md2
        superblock bytenr = 274877906944

    [All bad supers]:

All supers are valid, no need to recover
```

Then when I try to find root, I get the following results:

```
root@ubuntu:~# btrfs-find-root /dev/md2



parent transid verify failed on 2234898661376 wanted 199897 found 199895
parent transid verify failed on 2234898661376 wanted 199897 found 199895
parent transid verify failed on 2234898661376 wanted 199897 found 199895
Ignoring transid failure
Couldn't setup extent tree
Couldn't setup device tree
leaf free space ret -2088429181, leaf data size 16283, used 2088445464 nritems 353
leaf free space ret -2088429181, leaf data size 16283, used 2088445464 nritems 353
leaf free space incorrect 2234899513344 -2088429181
incorrect offsets 16007 16135
bad key ordering 0 1
bad key ordering 0 1
ctree.c:1720: leaf_space_used: Warning: assertion `data_len < 0` failed, value 1
btrfs-find-root(+0xb92b)[0x55974f83e92b]
btrfs-find-root(btrfs_leaf_free_space+0xd3)[0x55974f84093c]
btrfs-find-root(btrfs_check_leaf+0xef)[0x55974f840a41]
btrfs-find-root(read_tree_block+0x237)[0x55974f847dea]
btrfs-find-root(btrfs_find_root_search+0x23f)[0x55974f86bce7]
btrfs-find-root(main+0x297)[0x55974f875a94]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7fc9597b3b97]
btrfs-find-root(_start+0x2a)[0x55974f83e1ea]
incorrect offsets 2303983459 16233
leaf free space ret -2129775222, leaf data size 16283, used 2129791505 nritems 6
leaf free space ret -2129775222, leaf data size 16283, used 2129791505 nritems 6
leaf free space incorrect 2234900283392 -2129775222
ctree.c:1720: leaf_space_used: Warning: assertion `data_len < 0` failed, value 1
btrfs-find-root(+0xb92b)[0x55974f83e92b]
btrfs-find-root(btrfs_leaf_free_space+0xd3)[0x55974f84093c]
btrfs-find-root(btrfs_check_leaf+0xef)[0x55974f840a41]
btrfs-find-root(read_tree_block+0x237)[0x55974f847dea]
btrfs-find-root(btrfs_find_root_search+0x23f)[0x55974f86bce7]
btrfs-find-root(main+0x297)[0x55974f875a94]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7fc9597b3b97]
btrfs-find-root(_start+0x2a)[0x55974f83e1ea]
incorrect offsets 2303983459 16233
leaf free space ret -1023424776, leaf data size 16283, used 1023441059 nritems 584
leaf free space ret -1023424776, leaf data size 16283, used 1023441059 nritems 584
leaf free space incorrect 2234900299776 -1023424776
leaf free space ret -815266203, leaf data size 16283, used 815282486 nritems 409
leaf free space ret -815266203, leaf data size 16283, used 815282486 nritems 409
leaf free space incorrect 2234900332544 -815266203
leaf free space ret -815266203, leaf data size 16283, used 815282486 nritems 409
leaf free space ret -815266203, leaf data size 16283, used 815282486 nritems 409
leaf free space incorrect 2234900332544 -815266203
leaf free space ret -1124736152, leaf data size 16283, used 1124752435 nritems 272
leaf free space ret -1124736152, leaf data size 16283, used 1124752435 nritems 272
leaf free space incorrect 2234900561920 -1124736152
ctree.c:1720: leaf_space_used: Warning: assertion `data_len < 0` failed, value 1
btrfs-find-root(+0xb92b)[0x55974f83e92b]
btrfs-find-root(btrfs_leaf_free_space+0xd3)[0x55974f84093c]
btrfs-find-root(btrfs_check_leaf+0xef)[0x55974f840a41]
btrfs-find-root(read_tree_block+0x237)[0x55974f847dea]
btrfs-find-root(btrfs_find_root_search+0x23f)[0x55974f86bce7]
btrfs-find-root(main+0x297)[0x55974f875a94]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7fc9597b3b97]
btrfs-find-root(_start+0x2a)[0x55974f83e1ea]
bad key ordering 0 1
leaf free space ret -1124736152, leaf data size 16283, used 1124752435 nritems 272
leaf free space ret -1124736152, leaf data size 16283, used 1124752435 nritems 272
leaf free space incorrect 2234900561920 -1124736152
incorrect offsets 15864 15868
incorrect offsets 15864 15868
leaf free space ret -10051, leaf data size 16283, used 26334 nritems 79
leaf free space ret -10051, leaf data size 16283, used 26334 nritems 79
leaf free space incorrect 2234900594688 -10051
leaf free space ret -198844354, leaf data size 16283, used 198860637 nritems 246
leaf free space ret -198844354, leaf data size 16283, used 198860637 nritems 246
leaf free space incorrect 2234900594688 -198844354
leaf free space ret -10051, leaf data size 16283, used 26334 nritems 79
leaf free space ret -10051, leaf data size 16283, used 26334 nritems 79
leaf free space incorrect 2234900594688 -10051
bad key ordering 0 1
bad key ordering 0 1
bad key ordering 0 1
bad key ordering 0 1
bad key ordering 0 1
bad key ordering 0 1
Superblock thinks the generation is 199897
Superblock thinks the level is 1
Well block 2234900627456(gen: 199898 level: 0) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234899038208(gen: 199896 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234898726912(gen: 199895 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234898644992(gen: 199895 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234897727488(gen: 199893 level: 0) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234885406720(gen: 199882 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234877542400(gen: 199881 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234882310144(gen: 199880 level: 0) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234881654784(gen: 199874 level: 0) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234877165568(gen: 199863 level: 0) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234874789888(gen: 199863 level: 0) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234874560512(gen: 199863 level: 0) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234874429440(gen: 199863 level: 0) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 2234874216448(gen: 199863 level: 0) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
...
...
...
Well block 65680605184(gen: 150 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 65676771328(gen: 149 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 65671888896(gen: 148 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 65667973120(gen: 147 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 65664057344(gen: 146 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 65659895808(gen: 145 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 65656487936(gen: 144 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 65653243904(gen: 143 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 65650130944(gen: 142 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 65647165440(gen: 141 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
Well block 65644298240(gen: 140 level: 1) seems good, but generation/level doesn't match, want gen: 199897 level: 1
```

Based upon the answer, I should have to run:

```
btrfs check --repair --tree-root <block> --super <sup>
```

What should `<block>` and `<sup>` be?